# Why is this code not displaying the variable I returned in the method?

Tags: java

There is no error in the code, but when I try to call the method I wrote to check the string I input in the main, it's empty

[image]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Main m = new Main();

    m.balancedStringSplit("LLRRLLLRRRRLR");

}

public int balancedStringSplit(String s)
{
    int count = 0;
    int res = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
        if(s.charAt(i) == 'L')
        {
            count++;
        }
        else if(s.charAt(i) != 'L')
        {
            count--;
        }

        if(count == 0)
        {
            res++;
        }
    }
    return res;


}
```

Comment: Your program doesn't output anything, did you mean to use `System.out.println` somewhere ?

Comment: You are not doing anything with `res`. In your main method, you are simply invoking it. If you want to print, then you would need to replace this: `.balancedStringSplit("LLRRLLLRRRRLR");` with this: `System.out.println(m.balancedStringSplit("LLRRLLLRRRRLR"));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others pointed out above, you need to DO something with the return value of the method. It needs to be assigned to a variable so that you can then do something with it:

```
int i = m.balancedStringSplit("LLRRLLLRRRRLR");
System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys, i didnt use println, because i thought using return is enough to print out the result? and i called the method in the main.

Comment: The `int` in `public int balancedStringSplit(String s)` means that the method will return an `int` as the result of the method. You then need to capture that return value to be able to use it.